# error on running cap deploy:cold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rubber

when I run `cap [deploy:cold]` with rubber when deploying to amazon ec2, I get the following printed out endlessly on my console.
Please help with ideas. I followed railscast link here   http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2

```
servers: ["app01.foo.com"]
  [app01.foo.com] executing command
** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a setup problem.  Out of the box Rubber did not work for us.  You have to make a couple of modifications. The main fix for the problem you were having was in the mysql config:  config/rubber/deploy_mysql.rb

```
@@ -40,7 +40,7 @@
             pass = "identified by '#{env.db_pass}'" if env.db_pass
             rubber.sudo_script "create_master_db", <<-ENDSCRIPT
             mysql -u root -e "create database #{env.db_name};"
-              mysql -u root -e "delete from mysql.user where user='' and host='localhost';"
+              mysql -u root -e "delete from mysql.user where user='';"
           mysql -u root -e "grant all on *.* to '#{env.db_user}'@'%' #{pass};"
           mysql -u root -e "grant select on *.* to '#{env.db_slave_user}'@'%' #{pass};"
           mysql -u root -e "grant replication slave on *.* to '#{env.db_replicator_user}'@'%' #{pass};"
```

There was also setting the :asset role to :app that was holding us up for a long time.  That happens in deploy.rb and is according to the railscast above.